# Vimeo iframe is not displayed at the top of the div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to display Vimeo iframe responsive to the screen size.

I wrote the following

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.player {
  flex: 0 0 66.667%;
  max-width: 67%;
}

.lessons {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  max-width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Title
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="player">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/261210430?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="lessons">
    Lessons
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to have a box that captures 2/3 of the width and the other box for the playlist to capture the rest. This doesn't need to be accurate - but the idea is to have a player and a playlist, and the video iframe should start at top 0 of the div.

But as you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/zv6Lgaq7/1/ the video doesn't start at top 0 and capture the full size of the div.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing?

Comment: that's normal because the video (the images that makes the video) keep the same (width/height) value

Comment: @evgenifotia I would like the video to start at least at the top - as you can see there is a margin

Comment: @Roy the video doesn't start from the top of the frame, but rather has a margin

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/xv7toafu/

Comment: @evgenifotia thanks, but it doesn't capture the full width like in my jsfiddle. it needs to be 100% width and start at top 0 and left 0

Comment: you will need js. first get video height and width with the api https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos then get the width of the parent div of the iframe in pixel then calculate the value h = iframeHeight*parentWidth/iframeWidth now translate the iframe to the top by h/2

Comment: or just get the video height with api then update the parent div height

Comment: @evgenifotia would it set the iframe to be at top 0 left 0 of the parent?

Comment: I am not sure I got your example if it's a fixed height (I know the video)I can put it ahead. I want the video to stretch

Comment: so that you understand better let's start by why there is a margin. the answer is simple the video has is't own (width/height) value when this value is different from (parentDivWidth/parentDivHeight) the margin is added so that (newWidth/newHeight) === (width/height). the solution that I said is searching for this margin that was added to verify the equality (you can't stretch the video because that will change the Aspect ratio (width/height) value)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208352/discussion-between-dejell-and-evgeni-fotia).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how with js

```
function updater() {
  fetch('https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https://player.vimeo.com/video/261210430', {method: 'GET'})
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    const pw = document.getElementById('iframe').offsetWidth
    const h = data.height*pw/data.width

    document.getElementById('player').style.height = h+'px'
  });
}

updater()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j70kquLo/

this one is with better CSS https://jsfiddle.net/c7a0wdm5/

Comment: does it always work? I tried expanding the width of the output window of jsfiddle, and refresh and it would still display the margin

Comment: @Dejell that happen because there is no margin from top and bottom when the width is big enough. I fixed it

Comment: still doesn't work in wider screens. try to expand the result window and refresh

Comment: @Dejell check the link now I think this is what you are looking for. I changed CSS a little bit